# SCroll Qlabel in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hello am working on a project in python in my code i need to show extracted links from a google search and show it on my program interface , i used Qlabel but the links where a lot so i need to use scroll in Qlabel .

```
for i in range(len(links)):
            #print(links[i])
            
            w2 = QLabel('<a href=\"{urls}\">{urls}</a>'.format(urls = links[i]))
            w2.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
            
            w2.setStyleSheet('color: red')
            w5 = QLabel("-------------------------------------------------------")
            w5.setStyleSheet('color: green')
            self.vbox.addWidget(w2)
            self.vbox.addWidget(w5)
```

Comment: how to scroll the results am trying but with no success

Comment: is there somthing like scroll Qlabel  not Qlabel

Comment: Use a QTextEdit.